# How to calculate the percentage of NaNs by group?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

The dataframe looks like:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'tic': ['IBM', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'IBM', 'AAPL'],
                   'industry': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
                    'price': [np.nan, 5, 6, 11, np.nan],
                    'shares':[100, 60, np.nan, 100, np.nan],
                    'dates': pd.to_datetime(['1990-01-01', '1990-01-01', '1990-04-01', 
                                                 '1990-04-01', '1990-08-01'])
                    })
temp.set_index(['tic', 'dates'], inplace=True)
temp.sort_index(inplace=True)

Input [415]: temp
Out[415]: 
                industry  price  shares  
tic  dates                                  
AAPL 1990-01-01        B    5.0    60.0    
     1990-04-01        B    6.0     NaN    
     1990-08-01        B    NaN     NaN    
IBM  1990-01-01        A    NaN   100.0    
     1990-04-01        A   11.0   100.0
```

I want to drop the `tic`s (all the rows in the group) that have too many `NaN`s. How can I do filterations such as:

Drop the tics:

1. if > n% of values in column `share` are missing.
2. if > n% of values in column `share` OR `price` are missing
3. if n SUCCESSIVE values in column `share` are missing

Comment: You can do `sum(df.series.value_counts())/len(df)` to get percentage of  NAN as they do not show up in value count.  Is this all you needed to know?  No offense, but pandas dropna feature would probably be better than anything you can come up with.  You can see documentation here:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: @st19297 I won't speak for all of those who answer questions, but I can say this from my point of view. I saw your last question and thought it was fine to answer the five questions because it was easy enough for me to run through them. However, I answer questions for a few reasons. Only one of those reasons is "out of the goodness of my heart". Stackoverflow isn't a place to request others to code for you. We generally expect questions to include a modest effort. You've shown none. I find this disconcerting. read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @anshanno that gives me the percentage of `NaN`s in a column. I need this percentage for each tic, not column. I can get the counts for each tic using `temp.groupby(level=0)['industry'].transform('count')` If I get the number of `NaN`s like that, then I can divide the former by latter and get what I want.

Comment: @anshanno I have tried `temp.dropna(subset=[['price', 'shares']], axis=0, thresh = 2)`. Yes, it removes rows with `NaN`s on both columns. For example, it drops the 3rd row in the df above. But, I need it to drop the whole `AAPL` tic (the first 3 rows)